# How to use mysql connector NET in intelliJ (mac)

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea, jdbc, mysql-connector

I'm a macOS user and my editor is intelli j.
And I want to install Mysql connector "NET" but, I can't even install...
How can I use Mysql connector NET in intelli j???
(or should I use it in only VS code??)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect IntelliJ with local MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660104/how-to-connect-intellij-with-local-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL Connector/NET is for Microsoft C#/.NET, not for Java, so you cannot install MySQL Connector/NET and use it from IntelliJ. You need to use MySQL Connector/J, and you don't 'install' it. If you want to use it from within IntelliJ itself, you don't need to install anything, IntelliJ has it included (or will download it when needed).

If you want to use it from a program you write in IntelliJ, you will need to add a dependency to your [pom.xml](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-j-installing-maven.html) (Maven), or build.gradle (Gradle), or manually add a library to your project (if you're not using a build tool), see [How to add external library in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065402/how-to-add-external-library-in-intellij-idea).